# Why do you think we would like to have multiple methods blocks in class definition?Can I have multiple properties blocks as well?

Tags: matlab

Why do you  think we would  like to have  multiple  methods  blocks  in class  definition?Can I have  multiple  properties  blocks  as well?

Comment: Did you try adding multiple properties blocks?

Comment: i got error the the reason is me or i cant do that with matlab?

Comment: [Here is a classdef class](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/%40dip_image/dip_image.m) that I wrote that uses three `properties` blocks.